# TypeError compiling Vue web component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jovo-framework

I'm running a TypeScript based Vue project and am trying to build it as a web component using [@vue/web-component-wrapper](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-web-component-wrapper).

Related code:

```
// main.ts
import JovoWebClientVue, { JovoWebClientVueConfig } from 'jovo-client-web-vue';
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import wrap from '@vue/web-component-wrapper';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use<JovoWebClientVueConfig>(JovoWebClientVue, { /* cut */ });

new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');

const wrappedElement = wrap(Vue, App);

window.customElements.define('v-card', wrappedElement);
```

```
// App.vue
<template>
  <div id="app" class="w-screen h-screen">
    <chat-widget />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import ChatWidget from '@/components/ChatWidget.vue';
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
  components: { ChatWidget },
})
export default class App extends Vue {}
</script>

<style>
@import 'assets/css/theme.pcss';

#app {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
</style>
```

When running the build command:

`vue build --target wc --name my-custom-element ./src/main.ts`

I get the following error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (11:0)
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
|
> @Component({
|   components: { ChatWidget },
| })
```

Any idea how to resolve this? Appreciate all help - thank you.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/GarethBeddis/jovo-chatbot-web-component/src/master/